Advanced computing on FPGA
I am an absolute beginner in the FPGA topic (so far I have only implemented a couple of simple logic gates in Verilog and simulated them in ModelSim). I studied digital electronics, logic elements, flip-flops, counters at the university, but never took a course in the development of FPGA devices, only PLC programming.
I want to get my head around advanced computing on FPGAs. For example, are there commands for matrix multiplication, eigenvectors/eigenvalues, differentiation and integration, optimization, approximation, interpolation, etc. It is clear that all these calculations can be broken down into addition/subtraction/multiplication/division, knowing the algorithms for solving a particular operation. But I would still like to work at some more or less high level. Or is FPGA mathematics limited to binary arithmetic and nothing more?

You might get a more complete/informed answer from somewhere like electronics stack exchange, but my understanding is at least on the hardware level FPGA's primarily allow you to design how a configurable logic block (CLB) is setup, and how multiple CLBs are connected. Maybe some vendors provide some libraries/tools which implement these operations for higher level functions already.
